# PowerBI: Map Visualization not identifying Brazil state of "Pará"

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

The FILLED MAP visualization tool in PowerBI allows one to quickly build a map dashboard, but only if you prepare your data in the RIGHT way.

In my case, I'm trying to build a map of Brazilian states. I have columns for Cities, States, and the Country itself, and have categorized them as "City", "State or Province" and "Country" respectively. There are 26 different states in Brazil, and, while most of them have special characters (ã, á, õ, í, etc), typing them with regular characters usually allows PowerBI encoding to properly understanding.

However, for the state of "Pará", I can't make it appear correctly on the map.
I've tried every possible combination, writing the state field using every possible combination, but they always have the same result: either not appearing at all on the map, or appearing on the state of Pensylvania in US, as shown in the images below.
Every other state works perfectly when written without any special characters, without needing additional clues inside the cell (For example, the state of "São Paulo" is recognized properly when writting "Sao Paulo" in the state cell).

[Different combinations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mpOV.png)

[Issue shown on map. The red arrow shows where the state should be highlighted, the yellow arrow shows a wrongly placed state when using "Para, PA" in the state cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IHDA.png)

Is there anything I'm forgetting? An additional categorization step, or an internal ID code that I could use to refer to this specific state? The PowerBI documentation shows additional identifier codes for US and Canada states, but for Brazilian states, the only identifier seems to be the state name.

For reference, I'm using PowerBI Desktop, Version  2.96.701.0 64-bit in a 64-bit Windows 10 system.

Comment: I've tested it, not you not doing anything wrong, it looks like the visual isn't picking it up. But it is doing the other states around it in Brazil with out an issue. I would suggest raising support ticket with MS Power BI support to see what the issue is

Comment: Thanks, I've tried several different new variations, but none worked. The weird thing is, pinning cities inside of this state works perfectly, only the "whole state" filling fails

Comment: It could be the Bing Maps api that the visual uses. As mentioned open an Power BI support ticket, for MS to look into it. this may help, you're not the first to flag it
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Para-Brazil-no-longer-displays-on-the-Bing-Map/idi-p/1923977